# A Few Questions About CSS3/@Import and Validation CSS2.1

Tags: css, w3c-validation

This weekend, I made a template for a ficticious website. I do this every so often to try to build a very cleanly coded website template with minimal markup and very concise CSS.

I want my sites to validate perfectly before I hand them over to the client.

I have two problems ( I was wondering how others make a completely valid website ) using : http://validator.w3.org/check

I use some CSS3 properties (transitions, box-shadows, border-radius, etc) which make the site fail the validation since  the validator checks against the CSS 2.1 spec (I guess). Are there any methods you guys use to still pass the validator with these properties in the CSS? Do you seperate them and wrap them in conditional comments?

The second is the @import CSS method. In my header, I have one stylesheet called main.css. In this stylesheet, I have something like this:

```
/*site structure*/
/*@import url("grid_system_960.css");*/

/*default style rules
@import url("layout.css"); */

/*navigation.css
@import url("navigation.css");*/
```

I simply do it like this to keep the CSS modular and clean, but the @import also failed the validator.

Has anybody got any suggestions that I could take to improve my structure/method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want my sites to validate perfectly before I hand them over to the client..

Stop. Validation is a tool, not a competition. If you understand why the code fails and the consequences of how you deviate from the specification, then it isn't a problem.

> as the validator checks using CSS 2.1 spec

[image: The validator will use whichever profile you specify]

> The second is the @import CSS method.

Don't use this in production code. It increases the number of HTTP requests and slows the site down. Combine and minify CSS before publication.

> @import also failed the validator

Then you are using it wrong (probably by failing to make it the first thing in the stylesheet). "In CSS 2.1, any [@import](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import) rules must precede all other rules (except the @charset rule, if present)."

Comment: thank for your reply, it's much appreciated. So am I right to understand website development should not aim to always pass validation.. I've made a load of medium to large websites that dont pass validation but thought this was me being lazy..

Comment: You should **aim** to be valid, but when you understand and accept the full implications of a particular piece of code not being valid, then that is OK.

Comment: A small addendum here - I agree in general with Quentin, there are situations in which you understand a validation failure and make an informed decision to live with it. But you must keep in mind that validation helps to keep your code future proof - that failure may be ok today but you want to be sure you aren't exploiting a quirk which will disappear in the future.